# Upload image file to AWS EFS

Tags: amazon-efs

I have a task to store images in EFS storage from my React-Node app. On my website, user has to select a profile picture that should be saved in AWS EFS. I can find documentation to save images in S3 but I couldn't find the steps to save in EFS.

What do I need to do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to mount your efs storage on whatever machine. You should easily find documentation for this. After that it's a simple file write. In ither words treat it like it's part of your filesystem. Use fs module or fs extra to write to file system.